# Call onsearch method using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input element like this:

```
<input type="search" id="deviceSearchByName" placeholder="e.g. n90ap" onsearch="device.search(event);" title="Device Name" results="5" style="width:100px;height:15px;font-size:10px;">
```

I want to call its `onsearch` programmatically in jquery.

Something like:

```
$("#deviceSearchByName").search() //calls js function binded to onsearch
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why can't you do this $("deviceSearchByName").change(function(){//call event here});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

**HTML CODE**

```
 <input id="my_search" type="search" onsearch="alert(this.value);" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $( "#my_search" ).trigger( "search" );
```

The onsearch event is triggered both when the search input is submitted and when the user clears the search.

Note: only work in Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

As jQuery has no dedicated `.search()` property, you need to use `.trigger('search')` to trigger the 'onsearch' event.

Comment: no its not calling the js code. when I to `.trigger('search')`